# How to count the number of times each number is present in CSV column in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

So I have a CSV file that is organized like this,

```
Draw Date,Winning Numbers,Multiplier
10/15/2022,32 37 40 58 62 15,5
10/12/2022,14 30 41 42 59 06,5
10/10/2022,03 06 11 17 22 11,2
10/08/2022,13 43 53 60 68 05,2
```

I want to create two tables (one for winning numbers and one for the last number in winning numbers- the red ball) that lists info like this,

```
Whiteball Numbers | Times Drawn
1: 4
2: 33
3: 1 
etc... All the way until 69

Red Ball Number | Times Drawn
1: 
2:
3:
etc. up to 26
```

Basically, it needs to count how many times a specific number appears in the winning numbers' first 5 listed and how many times a specific number occurs in the last spot of the winning numbers category.

I've been able to set up the csv file, and I can write new information to it. But I cannot figure out how to count from the specific CSV column and only up to the first five and then just the sixth number, and get it to keep track of the count for each number.

Comment: Please add what you have tried so we may best assist you here.  Perhap sre-read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Can you describe the program you want to write in pseudo-code at least?

Answer (score 0):

Can you assumingly convert the csv into an array? Sure you can so therefore: just count the appearances of numbers into an object whose keys are the numbers and their values are the frequency they appeared.

```js
var csv = `Draw Date,Winning Numbers,Multiplier
10/15/2022,32 37 40 58 62 15,5
10/12/2022,14 30 41 42 62 06,5
10/10/2022,03 06 11 17 22 11,2
10/08/2022,13 43 53 60 68 05,2`;
var arr = csv.split("\n").map(function(row) {
  return row.split(",")
})
console.log(arr)

var counter_white = {}
var counter_red = {};
for (var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var list = arr[i][1].split(" ");
  for (var j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    counter_white[list[j]] = (counter_white[list[j]] || 0) + 1
  }
  counter_red[list[5]] = (counter_red[list[5]] || 0) + 1
}

console.log(counter_white);
console.log(counter_red);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important}
```